# split string into multiple output string

Tags: javascript

I'm having string like this

```
String input = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00"
```

I have tried lot of options by google-ing like indexOf() over load etc but could not get the exact result.

Is that possible I could have multiple output string on the basis of "|"

Expected output

```
String one = input.substring(0,input.indexOf("|")) = ABCD
String two = opt/kelly/box.txt
String three = DXC
String four = 20-12-2015 11:00:00
```

How can I do for the remaining ones ?

Any suggestion please how can I get this result using indexOf with substring.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: *"Is that possible that I could have..."* Yes. See the docs for [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) While you're there, be sure to review the documentation for other useful `String.prototype` methods.

Comment: You can save them to variables in modern browsers by using destructuring assignment, like so: `const [one, two, three, four] = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00".split("|")`

Comment: If there may be more data past the last variable that should be retained, you can use the *rest* syntax. `const [one, two, three, four, ...rest] = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00".split("|")` Any remaining values will be in an Array held by the variable `rest`.

Comment: Here's an example using `.indexOf()`: https://jsfiddle.net/shcrfod8/

Answer (score 4):

It's easy. All you need to do is to use [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var input = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00";
input = input.split("|");
console.log(input);
```

But if you need them in variables like `one`, `two`, etc., you might need to use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). You don't need to use `.indexOf` here.

**Using Destructuring assignment**

```js
var input = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00";
var [one, two, three, four] = input.split("|");
console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
console.log(four);
```

Comment: That's an example of [*destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), not the spread operator *(or more correctly, spread syntax, since there is no such operator)*.

Comment: @squint Fairly new to ES 6. I knew it. Thanks. `:)` Updated.

Answer (score 1):

First, be aware that JavaScript doesn't allow you to declare your data type as you are doing with:

```
 String input ....
```

You can only declare the variable (i.e. `var input ...`)

Barring that, the **[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** method (which splits a string based on your delimiter and returns an array of the parts to you) will do it.

Also, if you need to store each array element in its own variable, you can use a **[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)** to accomplish that.

```js
// Here's your scenario:
var input = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00";

var one = input.substring(0,input.indexOf("|")) // ABCD

// Do the remaining split on the original string without the already found parts
var [two, three, four] = input.replace(one + "|","").split("|");

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
console.log(three);
console.log(four);

// Here'e a cleaner alternative that uses a destructuring assignment:
var input2 = "ABCD|opt/kelly/box.txt|DXC|20-12-2015 11:00:00";
var [one2, two2, three2, four2] = input.split("|");

console.log(one2);
console.log(two2);
console.log(three2);
console.log(four2);
```

Comment: @Scott...Cant I do using this str.indexOf("is", str.indexOf("is") + 1); which gives king of nth index of character for every output string ?

Comment: @kelly That syntax will not *split* on the value of `"is"`. It will search for the existence of the string `"is"`, skipping the first occurrence and return the index position of any matches it finds.

Comment: ..please check my question ..I have add my string one output with using substring and indexOf. How can I extract the second, third and fourth..?

Comment: @kelly See my updated answer. Although, I'm not sure why you don't just split the whole string at once instead of getting just the first part and then dealing with the rest later.

Comment: @scott..because am storing the splitted strings into different string variables at the same time

Comment: @kelly I don't understand. If you want to split the main string into different variables all at the same time, then just use `.split()`, like in my second example. No need to make it any more involved than that.